# How can I make my variable used throughout my application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get the returned `memberID` variable inserted back in the other SQL stored proc?

```
  protected void imgBtnActivate_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Inserts Member record
    try
    {
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(ConfigManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString.Dev"]);

        DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.ins_member_p");
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@FirstName", DbType.String, txtFirstName.Text);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@LastName", DbType.String, txtLastName.Text);
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
        int memberID = Convert.ToInt32(db.GetParameterValue(dbCommand, "MemberNewID").ToString());

}
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "Notify Policy");
    }


    // Insert Member Email
    try
        {

Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(ConfigManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString.Dev"]);

            DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("[ins_MemberEmail_p]");
            dbCommand.Transaction = dbTran;

            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "MemberID", DbType.Int32, memberID);
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "SourceID", DBType.In32, 33);
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "EmailAddress", DbType.String, EncryptedEmailAddress);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "Notify Policy");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define `int memberID` outside the first `try....catch` block so that it'll be visible inside the second `try...catch` block:

```
protected void imgBtnActivate_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // define it here
    int memberID = -1:

    // Inserts Member record
    try
    {
        ......
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
        memberID = Convert.ToInt32(db.GetParameterValue(dbCommand, "MemberNewID").ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "Notify Policy");
    }

    // Insert Member Email
    try
    {
        ......
        // then it'll be visible and useable here!
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "MemberID", DbType.Int32, memberID);
        .....
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "Notify Policy");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change it like this, move the declaration of the variable out of the { }, before it

```
protected void imgBtnActivate_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

int memberID;

// Inserts Member record
try
{
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(ConfigManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString.Dev"]);

    DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.ins_member_p");
    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@FirstName", DbType.String, txtFirstName.Text);
    db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@LastName", DbType.String, txtLastName.Text);
    db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
    memberID = Convert.ToInt32(db.GetParameterValue(dbCommand, "MemberNewID").ToString());

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "Notify Policy");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would recommend that you split up your code a little bit.  You are doing quite a bit of logic (including data access and probably some domain logic) inside of your control event handler.

But the immediate solution to your problem is to delare `memberID` outside of your `try/catch` block.

```
 protected void imgBtnActivate_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    int memberID;
    // Inserts Member record 
    try 
    { 
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(ConfigManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString.Dev"]); 

        DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.ins_member_p"); 
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@FirstName", DbType.String, txtFirstName.Text); 
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@LastName", DbType.String, txtLastName.Text); 
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand); 
        memberID = Convert.ToInt32(db.GetParameterValue(dbCommand, "MemberNewID").ToString()); 

    } 
// .... so on and so forth
```

The above way you would have `memberID` within scope for that whole event handler, which in turn would allow you to use that variable throughout the scope of the handler.